# Default python interpreter In pyinstaller (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I am Doing A project on 2048 in pygame.

The program runs fine when double clicked , and also via command prompt. <- this is using c:\Python27\python.exe

However, when i use pyinstaller to try to change it into an exe , the following code gives an error:

```
class newSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        if filename != "0.png":
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.images=[]
            self.images.append(loadImage(filename))
            print(self.images[0])
            self.image = pygame.Surface.copy(self.images[0])
            self.currentImage = 0
            self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.topleft=(0,0)
            self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
            self.angle = 0
```

doing:

```
gameboard = newSprite("game board.png")
```

causes

```
TypeError:descriptor "copy" requires a pygame.surface object but received a "Nonetype".
```

When i run the script using the c:\Windows\py.exe , i get the same error.

I suspect that Pyinstaller is using c:\Windows\py.exe rather than c:\Python27\python.exe as its interpreter. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Update ! : It appears the problem is that the pyinstaller is not correctly bundleing my image files.I am however unable to add them despite spec file modifications

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the file name: "game_*space*_board.png". This is often leading to errors and should be avoided. To be honest, I do not know if this is the root cause for your problem, but worth trying.